# Custom pyGTK button

Tags: python, custom-controls, pygtk

I would like to create a button that I can control the look of the button using pyGTK. How would I go about doing this?

I would like to be able to point to a new image for each 'state' the button is in (i.e. Pressed, mouse over, normal...etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in [the API documentation for `gtk.Image`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkimage.html), "If you want to receive events on the image, such as button clicks, place the image inside a gtk.EventBox, then connect to the event signals on the event box.".

You probably want to use a `gtk.Image` rather than a `gtk.Button`, since buttons require more knowledge of how the theming engine works.  If you really want to use a button, you'll need to read up on [gtk rc files](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtktutorial/ch-gtkrcfiles.html#CH-GTKRCFILES) and the APIs for manipulating them.

Comment: Correct answer by Glyph, an Image inside an EventBox is probably the correct way. However, in general UI terms, changing the way a user has set buttons to look (using style-changes) is inherently a bad thing.

Comment: I definitely agree with that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way to use an image on a button.  Note that there is no text given when you initialize the button (self.button1 = gtk.Button()).  Adding text there would display the text instead of the image.

```
    self.image1 = gtk.Image()
    self.image1.set_from_file('images/home.png')
    self.image1.show()
    self.button1 = gtk.Button()
    self.button1.add(self.image1)
    self.button1.show()
    self.backupHBox.pack_start(self.button1, True, True)
    self.button1.connect("clicked", self.quit)
```